# process for updating a react app on server

Tags: reactjs, npm, pm2, git-pull, npm-build

I have a react/next.js app live on an ubuntu server, with nginx and pm2 running client side and server.js. I have made modifications locally and pushed the changes to github. I need to do a git pull. Do I need to stop pm2 or npm before I do a git pull? and after will I need to run npm build again? Downtime is not an issue.
Thanks

Comment: no .... yes ....

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I found the answer;

If updating the client side

sudo git pull     (pull changes from github)

sudo npm run build    (build react app again)

pm2 start npm -- start

If updating the server side

sudo git pull     (pull changes from github}

pm2 start server.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).